# Is Scaffold in rails 3.2 a better option?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, scaffolding

I am new to ruby on rails.I want to know why do we use scaffold and should we run scaffold directly after the bundle install process.
   I read somewhere that we have to first create controller by doing:-

```
rails generate controller
```

and then run the scaffold.
which one is the preferred method.
Create the model,controller then use scaffold or run scaffold directly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to build something in hurry and doesn't care much about the code, then you can scaffold. Once you scaffold a resource, rails  will provide you a basic/working crud operation, a restful route and all required views. You don't need to create model, controller, view and setup routes by yourself. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#getting-up-and-running-quickly-with-scaffolding

However, once you get to know the working of the rails and best practices, one generally prefer  not to use the scaffold and add the required components by themselves. This will allows the developer to customize and build the app the way they preferred.

Answer (score 4):

Rails provides these generators to quickly and easily create what you need. If you just need a model, you can run the model generator like `rails generate model ModelName attribute:type`. An example might be more clear:

```
rails generate model Post title:string body:string
```

Scaffolding generates all the major components of an application (models, views, controllers, routes, tests, even helpers, etc.) and running the scaffold generator is very similar:

```
rails generate scaffold Post title:string body:string
```

So if you want just a model, run the model generator, if you want just a controller, run the controller generator. If you want all those pieces I mentioned above to be generated with a single command, run the scaffold generator. Have a look at [Rail's guides on scaffolding](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#getting-up-and-running-quickly-with-scaffolding).

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank for the help guys.Actually i had created the model and running scaffold ,so the model was getting replaced.I will do it again @sergelerator,@AdamT,@ranendra

Answer (score 2):

Scaffolds are just a way to get up and running quickly. They are primarily used to mock stuff out quickly for proof of concept/demo sort of work. Most experienced developers never touch scaffolding. I would recommend you use a scaffold to see what it generates. Then try to recreate it without the scaffold.

When you run the scaffold generator it creates the model, controller, and views for you. It does it all in one shot.

When you run `bundle install` it gets **all** the gems (like a library) onto your system so you can run your app properly. Which gems? Well, `Rails` is a gem and it has many dependancies. When you run `bundle install` it will install all of those dependancies onto your system. Before you can start your rails app you will need to run `bundle install`.

Answer (score 2):

Scaffold is generally used for rapid prototyping. You dont need to run controller generate command since scaffold generator will automatically provide you with corresponding controller, model and views.

Hope this helps.